# Limit for some the variable in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have this limit but Mathematica can't solve it??!!

```
Limit[(f/n (-2  ArcTanh[(f/n  x)/Sqrt[4  a (1 - 2/(3 n)) + b x^2]]-Log[a (1 - 2/(3 n)) + k x^2]) + 2 Sqrt[b] Log[ Sqrt[b] x + Sqrt[4 a (1 - 2/(3 n)) + b x^2]]),  a -> 0]
```

Comment: Mathematica can solve it in 12.3.1: the result is: `ConditionalExpression[-((
   f (2 ArcTanh[(f x)/(n Sqrt[b x^2])] + Log[k x^2]))/n) + 
  2 Sqrt[b] Log[Sqrt[b] x + Sqrt[b x^2]], And[
 Re[b x^2] > 0, Re[k x^2] > 0, 
Inequality[-1, Less, 
Re[f n^(-1) x (b x^2)^Rational[-1, 2]], Less, 1], 
  Re[b^Rational[1, 2] x + (b x^2)^Rational[1, 2]] > 0]]`

Comment: Add this line:`Assumptions -> {n > 0, x > 0, k > 0, n > 0, f > 0, b > 0}` to `Limit` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: `FullSimplify[
  Limit[(f/n (-2 ArcTanh[(f/n x)/Sqrt[4 a (1 - 2/(3 n)) + b x^2]] - 
        Log[a (1 - 2/(3 n)) + k x^2]) + 
     2 Sqrt[b] Log[Sqrt[b] x + Sqrt[4 a (1 - 2/(3 n)) + b x^2]]), 
   a -> 0, Assumptions -> {n > 0, x > 0, k > 0, n > 0, f > 0, b > 0}],
   Assumptions -> {n > 0, x > 0, k > 0, n > 0, f > 0, 
    b > 0}] // InputForm`

Comment: results in the end of math `{((2*I)*(f*ArcTan[f/n] + n*Log[(2*I)*x]) - f*Log[k*x^2])/n, ConditionalExpression[Log[4] + 2*Log[x] - (f*(2*ArcTanh[f/n] + Log[k*x^2]))/n, f < n], 
 ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[2]*Log[8*x^2] - (f*(2*ArcCoth[(Sqrt[2]*n)/f] + Log[k*x^2]))/n, Sqrt[2]*f < 2*n]` in 12.3.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @user64494 - with 12.3.1 on a Mac `Assuming[{n > 0, x > 0, k > 0, n > 0, f > 0, b > 0}, Limit[(f/n (-2 ArcTanh[(f/n x)/Sqrt[4 a (1 - 2/(3 n)) + b x^2]] - Log[a (1 - 2/(3 n)) + k x^2]) + 2 Sqrt[b] Log[Sqrt[b] x + Sqrt[4 a (1 - 2/(3 n)) + b x^2]]), a -> 0] // FullSimplify]` evaluates to `ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[b]*Log[4*b*x^2] - (f*(2*ArcCoth[(Sqrt[b]*n)/f] + Log[k*x^2]))/n, f < Sqrt[b]*n]`

Comment: @BobHanlon: This results in `{(2 I (f ArcTan[f/n] + n Log[2 I x]) - f Log[k x^2])/n, 
 ConditionalExpression[
  Log[4] + 2 Log[x] - (f (2 ArcTanh[f/n] + Log[k x^2]))/n, f < n], 
 ConditionalExpression[
  Sqrt[2] Log[8 x^2] - (f (2 ArcCoth[(Sqrt[2] n)/f] + Log[k x^2]))/n, 
  Sqrt[2] f < 2 n]}` in 12.3.1 on Windows 10. The end of math again.

Comment: @user64494 - it seems odd that in evaluating a single expression that you get a result of a list of three expressions. Have you tried using `Clear["Global`*"]` prior to evaluating your code?

Comment: @BobHanlon: ClearAll["Global`*"]; saves math.

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple 2021 `limit(f*(-2*arctanh(f*x/(n*sqrt(4*a*(1 - 2/(3*n)) + b*x^2))) - ln(a*(1 - 2/(3*n)) + k*x^2))/n + 2*sqrt(b)*ln(sqrt(b)*x + sqrt(4*a*(1 - 2/(3*n)) + b*x^2)), a = 0)  assuming a>0,n>0,b>0, x>0,k>0;` outputs $$\frac{2 \mathrm{\sqrt{b}}\, \left(\ln\! \left(2\right)+\frac{\ln\left(b\right)}{2}+\ln\! \left(x\right)\right) n-2 f \,\mathrm{arctanh}\! \left(\frac{f}{n \mathrm{\sqrt{b}}}\right)-f \left(\ln\! \left(k\right)+2 \ln\! \left(x\right)\right)}{n} $$ without any conditions.